# Putting angular templating in the public folder

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, hottowel, public-html

For a job that I am interviewing for they use the hottowel generator from John Papa.  I have been working through it.  The organization is nice.  I am confused about the public folder containing the html files.  At my bootcamp and on the express generator we have always set our html in the server folder.  Is there a reason to do it this way?  I am wondering what would be the benefits and problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

We usually put templates that are to be monitored and manipulated on front end in "public" folder. While if the templates are to be maintained at back end, we put those in "server/client" or "server/views" folder. Naming of folder is not an issue. Like a login page with error message is to be kept on server side while shopping cart template may be put at front end side.

Comment: Agreed. Moreover, we like to keep all static assets defined for the client within one top folder to make it easier (in many server technologies) to ensure that the client only has access to permitted files. That's why it's called "public"

Comment: thanks for adding that... Only public assets should be manipulated at front end... so... both explanation renders to the same concept.